# I commited an svn file delete and now I want it back

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I deleted a bunch of files from my env and committed the changes.
Of course I now want one of them back.

What is the best way to bring the ONE file back out of the revision?

I have brought the file up from View History on the package (it is a java file), but don't see a way to bring it back short of copy and paste.

Eclipse 3.7.0, subclipse 1.6

**UPDATE**

It looks like Antonio Pérez and qor72 solutions both accomplish the goal. Antonio's can be done in eclipse but the number of reverts can be large. Also merge requests that one commit open changes.

I like qor72's solution. To access copy in this scenario:

1. look at the history and find the deleted file.
2. right click on file name and choose copy.
3. select the original directory.
4. OK.

Comment: If you only need one file, what's wrong with copy and paste?

Comment: In the case of copy and paste, I am assuming that svn will treat them as two different files, not the same file. This can cause problems with merges that combine two branches. What we know to be the same file, will cause a tree conflict on a merge.

Comment: @Aaron: It shouldn't be a problem if proceeding as I say in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done in the past is ressurrect the file [per the SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect), for example:

```
$ svn copy ^/calc/trunk/real.c@807 ./real.c
```

Then readd/commit and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the subclipse client would allow a simple way of doing it. But if you'd like to give a try to the command line client.

```
$ cd <working_copy_path>
$ svn merge repo_url[@M] repo_url[@M-1]
```

`M` is the revision where you committed the deleted files. And you should get back all the files you deleted as added files in your working copy. Then

```
$ svn commit <your_file_to_be_recovered>
$ svn revert (to remove the rest of added file that you don't need back)
```

[Further info on the `svn merge` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps to get it back

```
1. Identify the folder in the project which contained the deleted files.

2. Right click the folder, select Team  -> Merge 

Within Merge Pop up Window

3. On the URL tab, Browse and select the "repository resource to merge with" i.e the same folder in the repository.

4. Select Revisions radio button,

5. Click Browse button to select revisions.

6. Select the revisions which you want to be restored ( select the revision wherein you deleted the files / folders )

7. Enable Reversed merge.

8. Click Preview and check that it shows an entry for the file / folder which you plan to restore.

9. Click OK 

10. Eclipse now switches to SVN Merge and with the Synchronize view.

11. In the Synchronize view, right click the files you want and select Accept

12. In the Synchronize view, use the Synchronize SVN icon to switch from SVN Merge to SVN, where you can see the restored file as an outgoing change.

13. Right click the file  -> Team -> commit to check in the file again to the repository.
```